# Can mstest run without creating test results?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I'm trying to run mstest from command prompt as guided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx).

It works fine but I don't want to create the test results folder or test results every time it runs. How can I achieve that?

If it creates the test results files then it copies the whole test project DLLS inside that folder which I'm trying to avoid.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you run mstest.exe with /help switch will show that option /noresults is avaliable.
It works in my experience, I hope still helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with VS 2013. /noresults prevents the creation of the trx file, but it still copies all of the dlls into a timestamped folder.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I want to let you know how I solved it.

I simply put an rmdir after I have run the mstest in the post build. This cleans up any file and folder that mstest have generated. Something like:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:$(TargetFileName) /usestderr /noresults /noisolation
rmdir "D:\PathToTestResults\" /s /q
```

/s will remove any subfolder, and /q ensures it's done quietly.

Be careful with rmdir, and **make sure you point to the right path**, so you don't delete the wrong files and folders by mistake.

In the example I point to an absolute path, although I assume this could be done more elegantly.

I know that this doesn't answer the question in an exact way, as files are still generated by mstest. But as the end result is the same, I hope someone might find it useful afterall.